# CCnet devenv.exe error

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, devenv

I'm using cruise control .net and visual studio 2005's devenv.exe from the command line in a deployment task...but it's hanging up in devenv.exe immediately *after* a successful build, but before the rest of the cc process continues.  This whole process was working for over  a year, until I checked in a new web config today that merely included a new arbitrary constant for use in the rest of the program.  Reverging the web config did no good (because, well, why would it?).  I've tried simple fixes such as ending the process tree on devenv.exe on the build server and restarting the build server, all with no success.  Specifically, I'm getting a timeout error.  Doubling the time before timeout did not help at all.  It seems that devenv is hanging up the cc tasks from advancing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using devenv.exe instead of msbuild.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, is it possible that you're using some third-party library for which license expired?
I came across such situation once, then it popped-up with some window, which was blocking the whole process.

Have you tried to both run it manually without ccnet and then through ccnet console? Using the same user account that the ccnet normally runs on.